# Blackberry Widget development - VS.NET or Eclipse?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-widgets

Does anyone have any recommendations on what development environment should be used for the new Blackberry Widget development?

The reason that i'm asking is that i currently use the Java Plugin for Eclipse rather than the Visual Studio RAD plugin because the Visual Studio plugin doesn't give you access to most of the API functionality.

Is this the case with the widgets plugin or will you be able to access everything from the VS.NET plugin that you can with the Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: I haven't done any widget development for the BB.

BUT

When doing some research on BB development I found that RIM has provided a 'End of Life' notice for the Visual Studio plugin/runtime.

The BB link is:

[EOL Notice](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/rapidappdev/eolnotice.jsp)

So by default you are left with Java.

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks more like the RAD plugin for VS.NET that they're ending, one of the suggested paths is for Widget development so it looks like this should still be an option.